# Can I run scrapy spider with different setting in different process(parallel)?

Tags: scrapy

I define one spider with name='myspider', its behavior would be different according to the setting.And I want to run the spider with different instances in different process, is it possible?

I check the source code,it seems the SpiderLoader just walk the spiders module and I could just run one spider with the same name one time.

the running code seems:

```
for item in items:
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.set('item', item)
    settings.set('DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS', item.get('request_header'))
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl("myspider")
    process.start()
```

and of course, the error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xuanqi/workspace/github/foolcage/fospider/fospider/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 280, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1194, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1174, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 684, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Thanks advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Setting cannot be changed at runtime.
I suggest you to use spider argument to pass different variable to spider.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl("myspider", request_headers='specified headers...')
process.start()
```

And for doing this, you have to override **init** function of your spider to accept these variables. And pass the request_header to every Request object you use in the spider.

```
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(**kw)
    self.headers = kw.get('request_headers')
    ...
yield scrapy.Request(url='www.example.com', headers=self.headers)
```